# How does one bind to an indexed property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, indexer

I'm trying to bind a property like this:

```
public string this[string field] 
{
     get 
     { 
        // TODO: accessor code goes here
     }
}
```

...to a BoundField in a GridView. Something similar can be accomplished with e.g. a DataTable (by binding to a column name) but I'm stuck on how to get this to work with my own class. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

`<TextBlock Text="{Binding [someColumnName]}" />`